# Publish local branch to GitHub Repository

Tags: git, github

I'm slowly bumbling my way through learning open sourcy practices. Currently, I'm trying to submit a pull request to a repository that's on GitHub. I fixed a bug. Now, I'd like to submit it.

Before I began working on the bug, I created a branch. That branch is called `bug-fix/xyz`. I made my code changes. I then ran `git commit -m "Fixing bug #xyz"` from the command line. This commited the change to my branch locally. However, I noticed that my branch is not listed in GitHub. From my understanding, this means that I have not "published" the branch. In other words, the branch only exists locally.

When I run `git branch` from the command-line, I see:

```
* bug-fix/xyz
  master
```

The first line is listed in green. How do I push/publish this branch up to the remote repository on GitHub? I tried

```
git push [repositoryName] bug-fix/xyz
```

However, I received an error that says:

```
fatal: '[repositoryName]' does not appear to be a git repository.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Does the repository need to be a fully-qualified url? I can't figure out a) If I'm entering an invalid value and its something else or b) If some fully qualified url is needed since its GitHub. How do I find this value?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type:

```
git config -l | grep remote
```

You should see something like this:

```
remote.origin.url=ssh://myremoteserver.git
```

It indicates that the origin remote is pointing to ssh://myremoteserver.git

If it's not, you can add the remote server typing:

```
git remote add origin ssh://myremoteserver.git
```

The **origin** can be any name you want, but there's some convention to use origin as the main remote repo.

Having the origin pointing to the right remote repo, you just need to do

```
git push origin bug-fix/xyz
```

Done, this should work.